# attempt to index local 'ttlobj' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

```
p .  pginfo = function ( frame )
     local title = tostring(frame.args.title) or ""
     local ttlobj = mw.title.new( title )
     local txt = ttlobj.text
     if ttlobj.exists then
       if ttlobj .isRedirect then
         txt = txt .. " exists and is a redirect"
       else
         txt = txt .. " exists and is not a redirect"
       end
     else
       txt = txt .. " does not exist"
     end
     return txt
end
```

{{#invoke:Sandbox/Shreyansh Saboo|pginfo|title=}}
I am getting error how can I solve the error??
Please help me out with it.

Comment: Clearly, `mw.title.new` is returning nil.